# Why does the second series in my StackedColumn chart not start at y = 0?

Tags: c#, charts, mschart

I am having trouble displaying data.  My problem is that the first series i establish starts from "0" on y, but the second series starts at the y value from the series before it.  What do i need to adjust in my code to allow all subsequent series after the first to start at y = 0?

Code.

```
private void BuildGraph(machine_data[] array)
        {
            int series_cnt = 1;
            chart1.Series.Clear();
            chart2.Series.Clear();
            for (int x = 0; x < array.Count(); x++)
            {
                chart1.Series.Add(array[x].name + array[x].Digital_Location);
                chart2.Series.Add(array[x].name + array[x].Digital_Location);

                int numpoints = array[x].Multi_Datapoints.Count();

                for (Int32 i = 0; i < numpoints; i++)
                {
                    /***************************/
                    chart1.Series[array[x].name + array[x].Digital_Location].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Area;
                    chart1.Series[array[x].name + array[x].Digital_Location].Points.AddXY(array[x].Multi_Datapoints[i].dt, array[x].Multi_Datapoints[i].state);
                    /***************************/

                    chart2.Series[array[x].name + array[x].Digital_Location].ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn;

                    // Set up the charting location of the Series
                    if (array[x].name == "Preci_4")
                        chart2.Series[array[x].name + array[x].Digital_Location].Points.AddXY(0, array[x].count_1s);
                    else
                        chart2.Series[array[x].name + array[x].Digital_Location].Points.AddXY(1, array[x].count_1s);

                    // Set up the color of the series' according to which DIO they correspond to.
                    if (array[x].Digital_Location == "DIO0")
                        chart2.Series[array[x].name + array[x].Digital_Location].Color = Color.Green;
                    else
                        chart2.Series[array[x].name + array[x].Digital_Location].Color = Color.Red;

                    /*chart2.AlignDataPointsByAxisLabel();
                    return chart2;*/
                }
                series_cnt++;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out - I was making 4 separate series. I need only 2 series and to vary the x position. When I make 2 series I am then able to start from 0.